# Select records in SQL according to count of events in a time interval

Tags: sql, select, count, subquery, vertica

**First, an example of my table:**

```
+---------+-----------------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| user_id |      email      | home_phone | incoming_number |      date_time      |
+---------+-----------------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|       1 | dan@dan.com     |    8893432 |         5453455 | 2018-03-27 13:48:10 |
|       1 | dan@dan.com     |    8893432 |        65765489 | 2018-03-27 13:47:10 |
|       1 | dan@dan.com     |    8893432 |        65765489 | 2018-03-27 13:48:05 |
|       2 | sam@sam.com     |   16568675 |        65658403 | 2018-03-27 13:46:05 |
|       2 | sam@sam.com     |   16568675 |        57575748 | 2018-03-27 13:32:05 |
|       2 | sam@sam.com     |   16568675 |        76547946 | 2018-03-27 13:43:05 |
|       3 | allen@allen.com |   12345678 |        85768576 | 2018-03-27 13:46:05 |
|       3 | allen@allen.com |   12345678 |        65658403 | 2018-03-27 13:42:05 |
|       3 | allen@allen.com |   12345678 |        76547946 | 2018-03-27 13:43:05 |
|       3 | allen@allen.com |   12345678 |        76547946 | 2018-03-27 13:20:05 |
+---------+-----------------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

**What am I trying to accomplish?**

I want to select all the triplets `(user_id, email, home_phone)` that have at least 3 different incoming_number values within a time frame of 10 minutes.
For example, in the above table the result would be only `(3,allen@allen.com,12345678)`. the first user has only two distinct incoming_number values and the the second user has a time frame > 10 minutes

Notes:
an incoming number can appear more than once with different date_time value.

Each user_id has only 1 email and only 1 home_phone.

**What have I tried so far?**
I thought maybe i should treat the 3 first columns as 1 key? Maybe count distinct on the incoming_number and work it out somehow? Don't have much ideas.

What is the SQL query that will solve me that?

Comment: "within a time frame of 10 minutes" ... does this mean that all calls must be within 10 minutes of each other?  Also please tell us which version of SQL you are using.

Comment: No. It means that there are 3 different incoming_number values within a time frame of 10 minutes or less under this triplet. I am using Vertica

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  Do _all_ three triplets have to be within 10 minutes of each other, or could there be a chain of three where 1-2 are within 10 minutes and 2-3 are also within 10 minutes?

Comment: The chain is of incoming_number values and it's per triplet of (user_id,email,home_hone) this chain of 3 incoming_number values must be within 10 minutes. hence, this triplet must meet this condition: the  difference between the minimum date_time value of the chain and the maximum date_time value of the chain must be 10 minutes or less.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you right, none of your groups satisfies both criteria: 3 different incoming_number-s and duration between last and first call less than 10 minutes. So I added one group, with email match@match.com, that satisfies both criteria, for illustration purposes. The query below contains your data in a WITH clause, and all intermediate results for getting the criteria together in the final report. Remove the HAVING clause to check for those results in the rows that don't qualify ....

Happy playing

Marco

```
WITH
input(         user_id,email            ,home_phone,incoming_number,date_time) AS (
          SELECT     1,'dan@dan.com'    , 8893432  , 5453455       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:48:10'
UNION ALL SELECT     1,'dan@dan.com'    , 8893432  ,65765489       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:47:10'
UNION ALL SELECT     1,'dan@dan.com'    , 8893432  ,65765489       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:48:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     2,'sam@sam.com'    ,16568675  ,65658403       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:46:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     2,'sam@sam.com'    ,16568675  ,57575748       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:32:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     2,'sam@sam.com'    ,16568675  ,76547946       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:43:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     3,'allen@allen.com',12345678  ,85768576       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:46:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     3,'allen@allen.com',12345678  ,65658403       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:42:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     3,'allen@allen.com',12345678  ,76547946       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:43:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     3,'allen@allen.com',12345678  ,76547946       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:20:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     4,'match@match.com',62345677  ,85768576       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:11:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     4,'match@match.com',62345677  ,65658403       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:13:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     4,'match@match.com',62345677  ,76547946       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:18:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     4,'match@match.com',62345677  ,76547946       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:20:05'
)
SELECT
  user_id
, email
, home_phone
, MAX(date_time) - MIN(date_time) duration
, MAX(date_time) end_ts
, MIN(date_time) start_ts
, COUNT(DISTINCT incoming_number) incoming_number_count
FROM input
GROUP BY
  user_id
, email
, home_phone
HAVING MAX(date_time) - MIN(date_time) < INTERVAL '10 minutes'
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT incoming_number) >=3
;
user_id|email          |home_phone|duration         |end_ts             |start_ts           |incoming_number_count
      4|match@match.com|62,345,677|0 00:09:00.000000|2018-03-27 13:20:05|2018-03-27 13:11:05|
```

2nd Answer - seeing now what you're after, but keeping the original one:

In the case as you describe it, we need to go down the OLAP path.

We substract the 2nd preceding date_time from the date_time column (using LAG() ) and, as COUNT (DISTINCT col) OVER() is not supported in Vertica, we use Vertica's specific CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT() OLAP function to count how often the incoming_number changes , and get 0 if it never changes, 1 and 2 if it changes once or twice, giving 3 different incoming_number-s if it changes twice:

```
WITH
input(         user_id,email            ,home_phone,incoming_number,date_time) AS (
          SELECT     1,'dan@dan.com'    , 8893432  , 5453455       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:48:10'
UNION ALL SELECT     1,'dan@dan.com'    , 8893432  ,65765489       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:47:10'
UNION ALL SELECT     1,'dan@dan.com'    , 8893432  ,65765489       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:48:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     2,'sam@sam.com'    ,16568675  ,65658403       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:46:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     2,'sam@sam.com'    ,16568675  ,57575748       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:32:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     2,'sam@sam.com'    ,16568675  ,76547946       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:43:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     3,'allen@allen.com',12345678  ,85768576       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:46:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     3,'allen@allen.com',12345678  ,65658403       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:42:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     3,'allen@allen.com',12345678  ,76547946       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:43:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     3,'allen@allen.com',12345678  ,76547946       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:20:05'
)
,
w_filter_val AS (
SELECT
  *
, date_time - LAG(date_time,2) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date_time) AS time4these3
, CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(incoming_number) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY incoming_number) AS count_in_nbr_minus1
FROM input
)
SELECT * FROM w_filter_val ORDER BY 1;

 user_id |      email      | home_phone | incoming_number |      date_time      | time4these3 | count_in_nbr_minus1
---------+-----------------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------------
       1 | dan@dan.com     |    8893432 |         5453455 | 2018-03-27 13:48:10 | 00:01       |                   0
       1 | dan@dan.com     |    8893432 |        65765489 | 2018-03-27 13:47:10 |             |                   1
       1 | dan@dan.com     |    8893432 |        65765489 | 2018-03-27 13:48:05 |             |                   1
       2 | sam@sam.com     |   16568675 |        57575748 | 2018-03-27 13:32:05 |             |                   0
       2 | sam@sam.com     |   16568675 |        65658403 | 2018-03-27 13:46:05 | 00:14       |                   1
       2 | sam@sam.com     |   16568675 |        76547946 | 2018-03-27 13:43:05 |             |                   2
       3 | allen@allen.com |   12345678 |        65658403 | 2018-03-27 13:42:05 |             |                   0
       3 | allen@allen.com |   12345678 |        76547946 | 2018-03-27 13:20:05 |             |                   1
       3 | allen@allen.com |   12345678 |        76547946 | 2018-03-27 13:43:05 | 00:23       |                   1
       3 | allen@allen.com |   12345678 |        85768576 | 2018-03-27 13:46:05 | 00:04       |                   2
```

And in the end, all we need to do is to filter for less than 10 min duration and 3 or more incoming_number-s

```
WITH
input(         user_id,email            ,home_phone,incoming_number,date_time) AS (
          SELECT     1,'dan@dan.com'    , 8893432  , 5453455       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:48:10'
UNION ALL SELECT     1,'dan@dan.com'    , 8893432  ,65765489       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:47:10'
UNION ALL SELECT     1,'dan@dan.com'    , 8893432  ,65765489       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:48:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     2,'sam@sam.com'    ,16568675  ,65658403       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:46:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     2,'sam@sam.com'    ,16568675  ,57575748       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:32:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     2,'sam@sam.com'    ,16568675  ,76547946       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:43:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     3,'allen@allen.com',12345678  ,85768576       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:46:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     3,'allen@allen.com',12345678  ,65658403       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:42:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     3,'allen@allen.com',12345678  ,76547946       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:43:05'
UNION ALL SELECT     3,'allen@allen.com',12345678  ,76547946       ,TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 13:20:05'
)
,
w_filter_val AS (
SELECT
  *
, date_time - LAG(date_time,2) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date_time) AS time4these3
, CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(incoming_number) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY incoming_number) AS count_in_nbr_minus1
FROM input
)
SELECT * FROM w_filter_val WHERE time4these3 <= '10 MINUTES' AND count_in_nbr_minus1 + 1 >= 3
;

 user_id |      email      | home_phone | incoming_number |      date_time      | time4these3 | count_in_nbr_minus1 
---------+-----------------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------------
       3 | allen@allen.com |   12345678 |        85768576 | 2018-03-27 13:46:05 | 00:04       |                   2
```

Comment: Hi, I very much appreciate your answer, but the last group in my table do satisfies the condition. 
You should not check the MAX(date_time) - MIN(date_time) but if **exists** a group of 3 different incoming_numbers which lays within an interval of 10 minutes. in my example, the group of allen@allen.com do satisfy it - with the numbers 85768576,65658403,76547946. the last number also appears in the last line, at 2018-03-27 13:20:05. but it doesn't matter, since it also appears at  2018-03-27 13:43:05.
Anyway , I think i can work out with your answer somehow, it looks in the right direction.